# Require reactjs modules without Browserify, Webpack or Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, commonjs

I'm trying to setup TypeScript HTML app in visual studio. I want to use reactjs v0.14.7

I would like to avoid using tools like Browserify.

However, how to use the `react-dom` module then?

Let's forget about typescript for a while. I need to get pure ES5 up and running first.

currently, I have this:

```
<script src="Scripts/react/react.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/react/react-dom.js"></script>
<script>
    var Button = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (React.createElement("div", { className: "btn btn-default" }, 'hello world'));
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('Button'), document.getElementById('container'));
</script>
```

however, browser complains, ReactDOM object does not exists.

I have tried:

```
<script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/react/react.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/react/react-dom.js"></script>
<script>
   var React = require('react');
   var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
   ....
</script>
```

however, it does not work with require.js: Module name "react" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Can someone bring a little more light into this, please? How to use react without any server side tools like bundling, transpiling etc.

Answers like "use npm" won't be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and `require` are very different things - more on that later.

If you want to use React without a tool like Browserify or Webpack, then you don't necessarily need a module loader. The hosted versions of React and ReactDOM will expose global variables that you can use out of the box.

```
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.7.js"></script>
<script>
console.log(React, ReactDOM);
</script>
```

Just download these files if you want to work with them locally.

## SystemJS

All of that out the way, it sounds like [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and [JSPM](http://jspm.io/) might be exactly what you're looking for.

First use `jspm` to install your packages.

```
jspm install systemjs react react-dom
```

Then link and configure SystemJS.

```
<script src='jspm_packages/system.js'></script>
<script>
  System.import('app.js');
</script>
```

Now inside `app.js` you can write CommonJS style code.

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

SystemJS will handle the loading of the rest of your scripts. If you want to make a production build, then it's as simple as running `jspm bundle app`.

## CommonJS

The calls to `require` that you're seeing in the React tutorials and other examples are for a module format called [CommonJS](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html).

You use `require('react')` to get a reference to the value exported by the React module (installed into `node_modules` with npm). This means you need a pre-browser build step like Browserify or Webpack, that can staple all of the modules you need together and output one big script file.

## RequireJS

Confusingly, CommonJS and RequireJS use a function with the same name to specify dependencies. You're trying to use the RequireJS `require` function as though you were working with CommonJS modules.

If you want to import React with RequireJS instead, then you need to something like this:

```
<script src="js/require.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    'baseUrl' : 'Scripts/',
  });
  require(["react-0.14.7", "react-dom-0.14.7"],
  function(React, ReactDOM) {
    console.log(React, ReactDOM);
  });
</script>
```

When your code executes, RequireJS will go off and add script tags for the modules you've specified. Then once these scripts have loaded, it will pass the values that they export into the callback function for you to use.

Comment: Ok, I thought that CommonJS modules is a pattern and RequireJS is an library that impements the pattern. But RequireJS just allows to use CommonJS modules but with different pattern. Is that right?

Comment: RequireJS implements another format called AMD. CommonJS -> (Webpack | Browserify) -> Browser, AMD -> RequireJS -> Browser.

Comment: ok and now it is possible to load the commonjs modules with typescript and compile it into ES5 so it will work in browser without any other preprocessor?

Comment: You can't compile the code without a pre-processor, but you can use an [in-browser pre-processor](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-babel).

Comment: Well, typescript is my preprocessor

Comment: Compile your typescript into a file (like `app.js` from the above example), then use JSPM and SystemJS to load the other dependencies. You won't be able to load modules written in ES6, but most don't release them without first compiling back to ES5, so it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: I spent hours before seing this - thank you very much. Which is the most lightweight to use?

Comment: Depends what you mean by lightweight, [rollup](https://github.com/rollup/rollup) will probably produce the smallest bundle, but I think browserify is the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project

https://github.com/ORESoftware/hr4r2

it is doing what you want to do - it is using RequireJS + React + TypeScript. And it is doing serverside rendering *and* is a SPA.

This project is not using Webpack or Babel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example by Dan Abramov himself, the creator of Redux in which he makes a react app without using webpack, babel or browserify.

```
http://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/ZpvBNJ?editors=0010
```

In your HTML file inside your body tag write

```
<div id="root">
   <!-- This div's content will be managed by React. -->
</div>
```

And In your script tag type this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**PS** Make Sure You Include These 2 Libraries At Top

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js
```

Hope it helps.